# How do I do a left outer join in LINQ?

Tags: linq, join

Can anybody  explain in detail how to implement a left outer join in LINQ?

Comment: have your pick: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=linq+left+outer+join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key aspect here is DefaultIfEmpty()

Take a look at the following article to get a basic understanding. The example here is demonstrated for LINQ to SQL.

http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/06/10/c-left-outer-joins-with-linq/

If you are looking for LINQ to Objects example, then have a look at this

http://www.hookedonlinq.com/OuterJoinSample.ashx